# Routing and rendering React components server-side

Tags: reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript, react-dom, react-dom-server

I'm having a very difficult time trying to figure out what we should do to make React isomorphic. I'm following some tutorials and that's what I have right now:

- I created a `server.js` file that starts an Express server
- I created a `router.js` file where I created an Express Router object, imported the `ReactRouter` (`react-router`) and `ReactDOMServer` (`react-dom/server`) and there I set an Express route (`router.get('*')`) that fetches the ReactRouter trying to find a route to render (`ReactRouter.match`)
- For bundling purposes I created a allRoutes.js file that contains the `ReactRouter` directives. I set two paths, `/` and `/about`
- Two components, `Main` and `About`, each with a button and a click event. `Main` must be rendered in '/' and About in '/about'. Both components have `HTML`, `HEAD` and `BODY` tags and they refet to `bundle.js`
- app.js that sets React to the root-element in DOM.
- Webpack to create the `bundle.js` from the allRoutes.js file

I run into several problems, the first one was:

- Main is correctly rendered and Javascript works fine, but going to `localhost:3000/about`, the page takes like 5 seconds to load, it loads with no javascript behavior and I get a **checksum** error.
- Removing bundle.js from /about solves the checksum and heavy loading problems, but there is no Javascript behavior
- Bundling from allRoutes.js gives no errors like the above, but I have no javascript working in the page (though it's written in bundle.js)
- Setting /about as a child route of /, since Main don't cause problems, never loads the About component. The server only renders Main if a route is Matched.

As I was planning it, but I'm not sure this is what I should do to achieve isomorphic behavior, I am creating an entire HTML page in each of these root-components, About and Main. It seems to me more SEO friendly.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

app.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Main = require('./components/Main');

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Main),document);
```

router.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var Main = require('./components/Main');
var About = require('./components/About');
var React = require('react');
var routes = require('./routes');

router.get('*', function (req, res) {
    var props = {};
    ReactRouter.match({
        routes: (
          routes
        ),
        location: req.url
    }, function (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
        console.log(renderProps)
        if (renderProps) {
            // se encontrou uma rota, responde o HTML referente ao componente que foi preprocessado no backend
            res.send(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <ReactRouter.RouterContext {...renderProps} createElement={
                    function(Component,renderProps){
                        return <Component {...renderProps} {...props} />
                    }
                } />
            ));
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not found');
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

routes.js

```
//routes.js
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var React = require('react');
var Main = require('./components/Main');
var About = require('./components/About');

module.exports = (
  <ReactRouter.Router history={ ReactRouter.browserHistory }>
      <ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={ Main } />
      <ReactRouter.Route path='/about' component={ About } />
  </ReactRouter.Router>
);
```

webpack

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './routes.js',
    output: {
        filename: './bundle.js',
        path: 'public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

about.js

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({   
    _handleClick: function(){
        alert('Sobre!');
    },
    render: function(){
         return (
             <html>
                <head>
                    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css' />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h1>About</h1>
                    <button onClick={ this._handleClick }>About</button>
                    <script src='/bundle.js'></script>
                </body>                
             </html>                      
         );
    }
});
```

server.js

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['react']
});

var React = require('react');
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.use(require('./router'));

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Started at 3000');
});
```

@editing

I changed allRoutes (routes.js) to this.

```
<ReactRouter.Router history={ ReactRouter.browserHistory }>
      <ReactRouter.Route path='/' component={ Main } >
        <ReactRouter.Route path='about' component={ About } />
      </ReactRouter.Route>
  </ReactRouter.Router>
```

Now About is child of Main, Javascript works in Main, but About is never loaded. Trying to access a non-existing route shows me a 404, but any route that is mapped renders Main. What is going on?

@resolved
found a solution:

https://github.com/victorsferreira/react-isormorphic/

Comment: Hi @victor, please share if you found an answer or the repo link with some code examples for your solution. Thanks!

Comment: I will update the answer with a link on github and later I try to explain what was done

Comment: Yes please @victor Ferreira.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but any news yet?

Comment: hey, @punkbit i updated the answer with a github link the same time I answered you https://github.com/victorsferreira/react-isormorphic/ clone it and run the script